# Facebook really disabled user_mobile_phone permissions?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've found this link:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/

but it is from January 14, 2011, maybe facebook enabled it again.

someone knows it? and if is there a way to get the user mobile phone.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Facebook removed the permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/) - and the access to those fields - and has not yet decided to make them available to applications again. So, no you cannot access this data.

Comment: ey man i got a last question about it, even if i got a white list app i can get the mobile number of the user?

Comment: That's the same question. It has the same answer.